# How can I add properly the version or a table database in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I saw while ago that we can update the wordpress tables based on the `add_option(db_version)`. Therefore, my question is how can i properly add this version option an check if the table values change based on the current version.

This is how the code looks.

```
   // global $agro_db_ver;
    global $wpdb;

    // $db_name = DB_NAME;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table1';
    $table_user = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name(
        ID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        userID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES $table_user(ID)
        ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
    dbDelta($sql);

    // Adding version control
    add_option('agro_db_ver', '1.0.0');'
```

But the database in the activate hook doesn't show the version. How can I check table changes?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see an error in your code. I am not sure it's came when you ask question. But I run your code `add_option('agro_db_ver', '1.0.0');` in a page template in my local which worked fine.

Could you please try to use update_option function?

Answer (score 1):

your can define constant variable with latest version value and u need to check option value from DB to verify version value with your constant value and update if not latest

Comment: I've tried with a global varible like so.

// Define global db_variables
$agro_db_ver = '1.0.0';
global $agro_db_ver;
define('agro_db_ver', '1.0.0'); 
b

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with a global varible like so.

```
    // Define global db_variables
       $agro_db_ver = '1.0.0';
       global $agro_db_ver;
       define('agro_db_ver', '1.0.0');
```

But triggers and error in definition, in the database WordPress does not recognize that option, I would try with update_option as mentioned @fahad. After that, validated your suggestion, Thanks so much @Janki